# How to display string plus curl variable?

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I need to get this to display correctly like this:

```
Public IP Address . . . . . . . . : (my ip address)
```

here's what I have for now:

```
set c=curl "http://icanhazip.com/"

set /p t="   Public IP Address . . . . . . . . : %c%
```

trying to display curl alone as %c% works as it should but when adding it to string or echo it doesn't, any idea?

Comment: So you are taking input where it will prompt `Public IP Address . . . . . . . : <IP>`?

Comment: that's what I'm currently getting but I need to get it to show like this "Public IP Address . . . . . . . . : 142.94.37.204"

Comment: Setting a variable to `curl "http://icanhazip.com/"` the variable will become equal to the string `curl "http://icanhazip.com/"`. To set a variable as a command output, use a `for` loop.

Comment: Use `for /f %%a in ('curl "http://icanhazip.com/"') do (set c=%%~a)`

Comment: It's working :D however I'm getting some random text "% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16  100    16    0     0     16      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01    85" it displays right before "Public IP Address . . . . . . . . : (my ip)"

Comment: pipe the result of your `curl.exe` command through `find.exe`, e.g. `('curl "http://icanhazip.com/" ^| find "Public IP Address"')`

Comment: Or change your options. Depending upon your specific task, one or a combination of `[-f|--fail] [-S|--show-error] [-s|--silent]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Neko Musume, `for /f %%a in ('curl -s "http://icanhazip.com/"') do (set c=%%~a)`
this solved it.